# Getting error "In function '_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'" have not been able to use answers from similar questions to solve

Tags: c, linux, program-entry-point

I'm new to c and keep getting this error In function '_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'. I know this is a common error but have not been able to use other answers here to solve.

I'm trying to compile my "main.c" and my "memcheck.h"

my main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "memcheck.h"


int main () {
  int *ptr;

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    free(NULL);
return 0;
}

void *memcheck_malloc (size_t size, char *file, int line){
return NULL;
}
void memcheck_free (void *ptr, char *file, int line){
}
```

my memcheck.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef MEMCHECK_H
#define MEMCHECK_H

#define main memcheck_main
#undef malloc
#define malloc(size) memcheck_malloc(size, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#undef free
#define free(ptr) memcheck_free(ptr, __FILE__, __LINE__)


void *memcheck_malloc (size_t size, char *file, int line);
void memcheck_free (void *ptr, char *file, int line);


#endif
```

This is the error I receive:

```
$ gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -include memcheck.h main.c -o main
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You get this problem because writing macros with the same name as standard library functions is a royally stupid idea. You also can't `#undef` functions. Nor can you replace them with functions of a different function signature. The appropriate way to do this is to write a _wrapper function_ instead.

Answer (score 5):

You do not have a main() function due to:

```
#define main memcheck_main
```

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are making a memory leak debug tool?

Just remove the:

```
#undef malloc
#undef free
```

and don't redefine your main function...

```
#define main memcheck_main
```

Otherwise, you could also use "Valgrind" to test for memory leaks (and much more).